# IE8 addon, coded in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, bho, ieaddon

I've made a small IE8 add-on, the button in the tools bar appears as it should be, but once it is clicked, gives error:

```
Script: secret
Line: 1
Char 8
Error: Expected ';'
Code: 800A03EC
Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error.
```

The `.js` was saved under utf-8, checked with three complicators, there are no syntax errors or ';' missing in there.
The script is of 20 lines, and pretty much all of them  are getElementById() functions.
The first line is a mirror to: `var secretVar = document.getElementById('secretId').value;`

Yes, I tried `content.document.getElementById('secretId').value`;

but the same error appears.

Is there something specific that I am missing in the script?
Should there be an additional line to target exactly the page on my IE?

Comment: Try this http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-800a03ec-errors.html maybe it's useful.

Comment: is it possible that when the script was saved with notepad, IE interprets it not with utf8, but with different encoding and therefore gives errors because instead of, e.g. a space, it gives other symbol?

Comment: As I thing notepad will use Default settings for encoding when you save the file. Try to use "Save as" and their is a option to change encoding when you save the file.

Comment: as mentioned, I saved it as utf8 with notepad. :)

Comment: The resolution is quite simple:

Comment: The addon initial file has to be saved in .html in <script> brackets, only then it loads as it should.